# Why is my PHP inserting the correct amount of rows but in the rows there are no data?

Tags: php, mysql, session, html-table, get

I am trying to add a script that makes a request to my MySQL database and displays the data back in an html table. At the minute the request is made and the amount of rows in the table corresponds to the amount of rows in the mysql data however no physical data is there.

The code that I am trying to use is:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:2em;margin-bottom:33em;">
  <table border="1" class="table table-striped" style="margin-top: 2em;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>passcode</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    // ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    // error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="wvptszyl_sc"; 
    $password="wvptszyl_sc";
    //!@#$%^&*(
    $db="wvptszyl_sc";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
    //mysql_select_db($db);  
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno($conn) . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn) . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
    @session_start();
      $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, passcode FROM admin");
      $result->execute();
      for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['id']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['username']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['passcode']; ?></label></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

At the minute there are 2 rows in the table and 2 rows are inserted however what I was hoping for was the data to be displayed in the rows.

Comment: What is `print_r($row):`???

Comment: Also, `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Don't supress your errors. Remove `@` and enable display errors

Comment: I'm woundering why rows should be displayed at all. You are mixing procedural and OOP style mysqli. `mysqli_connect` returns a resource but an object. Use `$conn = new mysqli(`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone That is unlikely to be a cause of the problem OP is having.

Comment: @Dharman You are right. Indeed `mysqli_connect` is just an alias for `__construct` returning an object on static call. One strange thing more in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You have misunderstood the for loop. It's used to repeat specific actions until the specified condition is false. Your condition is an assignment, so there's the error.

So change this

> for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

to this:

```
foreach ($result->fetch_all() as $row) {
```

$result->fetch_all() returns an associative array of the data. 
With the foreach loop, you access every element in that array and can access it with $row['any-key-you-want']

Comment: While this might be a legitimate answer to OP's problem, you still need to improve the quality of your answer. Try not to post answers which still require clarification. If you have identified the problem you need to explain why it happens an what is the best way to fix it.

Comment: Edited my answer. Now okay?

Comment: Not really, it's a little worse. What is that bit about `for` statement being invalid? `fetch_all` returns associative array, a numeric array, or both. Why replace `fetch` with `fetch_all` and still loop on it?

Comment: The `for` loop is equivalent to `while($row = $result->fetch())` here since `$i` is never used. This should not be the problem. @Dharman I dislike `fetch_all` too since it is a resource impact on large tables.